# Is it possible to sort code via Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-5.0, code-cleanup

CodeRush has this nifty plugin called cr_ClassCleaner that allows me to sort the elements in the class (e.g. methods, private variables, etc...).

Can Resharper 5.x do this, either via the product or plugins?

Comment: You'd have to be really careful with a feature like that.  If someone use that on a file, while also making some changes, and checked it in, I wouldn't be able to tell what they did to the code.  Sounds dangerous.

Comment: Yes it can. Also, if you like coding style plugins check this: http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/

Comment: generally resorting code is a dangerous thing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - ReSharper, Tools, Cleanup Code.

They [recently blogged about customising the type layout this generates](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/).

Answer (score 4):

There is an option in code cleanup to reorder type members. This would be done as part of a full cleanup. If you wanted to only reorder, you could create a cleanup profile that only included that step. You can have multiple cleanup profile.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+Alt+F (if you're using the IDEA profile) will take you to the cleanup code menu where you can achieve that.

Comment: I am looking at the Cleanup Code dialog, there is an option to reorder code elements.  If I proceed with it, it does not sort the methods.

Comment: I don't think it reorders the contents of each group by default, no. But you can configure it to - see [Sorting, Grouping and Regions](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/)  at the bottom of this blog post.